# Finite Borel regular measure $\mu$ on a topological space which is equal to $1$ for every neighborhood of some point.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be some topological space, and $\mu$ finite Borel regular measure on $X$. If for some $x \in X$, it holds that for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ we have $\mu(U)=1$ , does it follow that $\mu$ is $\delta_x$?

I have seen that statement being used for compact Hausdorff space, and intuitively it seems to make sense (for Hausdorff spaces at least), but I can't find the rigorous way to prove that.

Comment: We don't need compactness or Hausdorff.  If $S\ni x$ is an arbitrary Borel set, then outer regularity immediately implies $\mu(S)=1$.  Taking complements we have $\mu(S)=0$ whenever $x\notin S$.

Comment: @MW Thank you. It makes sense now.